# MSAL get token with WPF .NET Core 3.1 app

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to get an AD token and am following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop

I follow the steps in WPF .NETFramework 4.7.2 and it works perfectly.  When I recreate that program in WPF .NET 3.1, I have issues logging in.  Instead of the window appearing on top of the app like in .NETFramework it opens a browser webpage to login.  Once logged in it goes to a new page with the following error:

> We're unable to complete your request invalid_request: The provided
> value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The
> expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for
> this client application.

Note:  If I create the msalcache.bin3 file via the .NETFrame test app, the .NET Core app can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Core does not support the embedded browser that the .NET Framework sample uses to acquire the token. You must set the redirect URI to `http://localhost` in both the app registration and in code (or use default reply uri).

See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Default-Reply-Uri